# Error: unused arguments in R. Passing 2 arguments for 2 parameters

Tags: r

I'm doing HW in R but keep running into an error

```
Error in kknn(V11 ~ ., data[train.idx, ], data[test.idx, ], k = k) : 
  unused arguments (data[test.idx, ], k = k)
```

When I try to run `kknn(data_mode, 1)`

Here is the code

```
data <- read.table("breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  header = FALSE,
                  sep = ",")
data_mode <- data

#KNN MODEL
library(kknn)

train.idx = sample(nrow(data), size = floor(nrow(data) * 0.7))
test.idx = setdiff(1:nrow(data), train.idx)

acc = matrix(ncol=5, nrow=5)
kknn = function(dataset, number) {
  for (k in 1:5) {
    knn_model = kknn(V11~., 
                     data[train.idx,], 
                     data[test.idx,],
                     k=k)
    pred = as.integer(round(fitted(knn_model)))
    acc[k,i] = sum(pred==data[test.idx,]$V11)/nrow(data[test.idx,])*100
  }
}

kknn(data_mode, 1)
```

expecting the function to pick up `data_mode` and `1` as variables

Comment: You are overwriting `kknn` with your own function, which means when you try to run the function `kknn` from the package inside your own function, you are actually calling your _own_ function from inside itself. This is where the error is occurring. Either call your own function something different, or specify `kknn::kknn` when using the package function inside your own function.